# Retrieve details of item removed from publishing queue

Tags: publishing

Is there a way we can get the details of item removed from publishing queue using tridion 2013 SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing an item from the publishing queue means you deleted the details about that publish action.

There is no way to restore these details, similar to when you delete an item, you cannot recover it either (unless you would consider a database restore).

What will remain available is the publish status on the item.